# How are registers shared among threads?

Tags: cpu-registers

I know that stacks are per thread, but registers are limited,like on IA32,only 8 registers.

So how are registers shared among threads?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Registers are used by the CPU when it's currently running a particular thread. When the OS decides to switch from one thread to another, the OS *saves* the current values of all the register into a private memory area specific to the first thread. Before the second thread starts running, the OS loads the values of all the registers from *its* saved area. This is called a [context switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch).

Comment: Hi @Greg Hewgill +1. I asked a question about this, could you explain me how global variables are saved in a thread? THANKS IN ADVANCE