# Impact on memory visibility if single thread is scheduled on to multiple cores

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduling, multicore, cpu-cache

This question is specifically about JVM & the memory visibility guarantees

Suppose that I have a thread `t1` that accesses a variable on heap say `x`

Suppose the thread is scheduled to be executed in core `c1` & has modified `x` in registers (after fetching from RAM) & `x` has to be moved out of registers because `t1` needs to execute few more instructions which require additional data to be loaded into the registers. So in effect `x` is in `c1`s cache instead of registers

Now, OS schedules another thread `t2` into `c1`, so cpu registers are filled with new data, but we still have capacity in the cache for `x` (in effect, I'm implying that the cache might not have been flushed to RAM/L3. This is an assumption of mine, not sure if it indeed is the case)

After a while OS schedules original `t1` thread on to a new core `c2`, Is `t1` still required to see the latest value of `x` in `c1`s cache in all circumstances?

If `t1` in `c2` does not see the latest `x` in `c1`, I believe we will be violating Sequential consistency of JMM

Am I wrong?

PS: I have already read this other thread that talks about same/similar problem, But it has not addressed the question to my satisfaction. So reposting it here

[Data visibility on multi-core processor by single thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40256057/data-visibility-on-multi-core-processor-by-single-thread)

Comment: The Java specifications says that "Each action in a thread happens-before every action in that thread that comes later in the program's order." (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html). So the JVM guarantees that what you're describing can't happen.

Comment: "If t1 in c2 does not see the latest x in c1..." Cache coherency protocols ensure that is `x` is modified in a cache, no other cache can see an outdated value.

Comment: @JBNizet, your comment should really be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't worry about cache related inconsistencies. JMM hides all hardware-specific memory model details from you. So adhering to it and avoiding race conditions from JMM standpoint is enough.

If you are concerned about such low level details then in case of x86 you might want to read Intel manual Vol 3A, chapter 8:

> These multiprocessing mechanisms have the following 
>   characteristics:
>
> [...]
>
> • To maintain cache consistency — When one processor accesses 
>   data cached on another processor, it must not 
>   receive incorrect data. If it modifies data, all other processors that
>   access that data must receive the modified data.
>
> [...]

That should be convincable enough so not to worry about cache inconsistency at least on x86 :)